# "Я на тебя удивляюсь" or "я тебе удивляюсь"

Tags: словоупотребление, глаголы

Choosing between "я на тебя удивляюсь" and "я тебе удивляюсь" - which is correct as the object of the verb `удивляться`?

Answer (score 3):

Please, use only удивляться + Dative, the other variant should only be understood if pronounced by another person. Wherever you can find it, it is not a current norm. 
So, **удивляюсь тебе**, **удивляться этому**, **удивляться чему-то, кому-то**.

Удивляться на кого-то is a more colloquial form not typical of educated people. It could be just fine at Tolstoy's time, or in the direct speech of a charachter, to add a certain trait to him. But even Rhozenthal marks this phrase as a rarer one.

Comment: it would be nice if you explain why exactly you think so - as I've mentioned form "на тебя", "на себя" is far from moribund.

Answer (score 1):

**Both forms are valid but whenever you are in doubts - prefer "я тебе удивляюсь"** form.

Well quite often it is stated that correct form is "я тебе удивляюсь", and any editor will cringe encountering "я на тебя удивляюсь". However this is not true at all. It's not only de-facto colloquial usage - "удивляться на кого-то, что-то" one can [find in classic literature](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2367/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), like in "Нехлюдов удивлялся сам на себя". Or, here's another [quote](http://az.lib.ru/l/lejkin_n_a/text_1903_kupetz_prishel_oldorfo.shtml):

> Но я удивляюсь на тебя, Лев. Куда девался твой гонор, твоя амбиция!

Comment: Удивляться кому, чему, но удивляться на кого (только одушевленное)